# Unique values in column created using cross join and edited with STUFF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to take a column from one table and clean it from unneeded stuff and from some words matched from another table. I got this code

```
create table dbo.abbEx(
    name nvarchar(50),
    full_name nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO abbEx
    (name, full_name)
VALUES
    ('DT','Delete This'),
    ('NN','Not Needed'),
    ('CM','Cut Me');

create table dbo.wordsToEdit(
    names nvarchar(50),
)

INSERT INTO wordsToEdit
    (names)
VALUES
    ('Delete This "THIS MUST NOT BE DELETED" Delete This'),
    ('DT HELLO WORLD'),
    ('SAVE THIS WORDS N"N'),
    ('THIS ONE WASNT EDITED'),
    ('THIS ONE -CM WASNT EDITED TOO'),
    ('Cut     Me EDITED ONE');

select distinct RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(wte.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))) as orig_name, edited_name FROM wordsToEdit wte
       cross join (select RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(STUFF(ISNULL(STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name),
                                    ''),RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                    PATINDEX('%'+a.name, ISNULL(STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name),
                                    ''),RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))))),len(a.name),
                                        ''), STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name)+1,
                                    '')))) as edited_name
        from (select name from abbEx union select full_name from abbEx) a
         cross join (select names FROM wordsToEdit) b) c
```

Then I need to do some more work with edited_name column, but what I get there is:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|   orig_name                                                   |   edited_name                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   cut me edited one                                           |   <null>                          |
|   cut me edited one                                           |   edited one                      |
|   cut me edited one                                           |   hello world                     |
|   cut me edited one                                           |   save this words                 |
|   cut me edited one                                           |   this must not be deleted        |
|   delete this this must not be deleted delete this            |   <null>                          |
|   delete this this must not be deleted delete this            |   edited one                      |
|   delete this this must not be deleted delete this            |   hello world                     |
|   delete this this must not be deleted delete this            |   save this words                 |
|   delete this this must not be deleted delete this            |   this must not be deleted        |
|   dt hello world                                              |   <null>                          |
|   dt hello world                                              |   edited one                      |
|   dt hello world                                              |   hello world                     |
|   dt hello world                                              |   save this words                 |
|   dt hello world                                              |   this must not be deleted        |
|   save this words nn                                          |   <null>                          |
|   save this words nn                                          |   edited one                      |
|   save this words nn                                          |   hello world                     |
|   save this words nn                                          |   save this words                 |
|   save this words nn                                          |   this must not be deleted        |
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   <null>                          |
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   edited one                      |
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   hello world                     |
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   save this words                 |
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   this must not be deleted        |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   <null>                          |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   edited one                      |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   hello world                     |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   save this words                 |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   this must not be deleted        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

and what I need is:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|   orig_name                                                   |   edited_name                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   cut me edited one                                           |   edited one                      |
|   delete this this must not be deleted delete this            |   this must not be deleted        |
|   dt hello world                                              |   hello world                     |
|   save this words nn                                          |   save this words                 |
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   this one cm wasnt edited too    |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   this one wasnt edited           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

If I put all the select from the first cross join into ISNULL and return orig_name is the result of STUFF is null, there will be all of the unedited strings from orig_name in edited_name column.

What I need is if the string was edited with abbEx, add edited value to the edited_name column, and if it wasn't, add orig_name to edited_name instead of null as you can see here:

```
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   this one cm wasnt edited too    |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   this one wasnt edited           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

And all this value must be unique.
How can I do this?

There's definitely something wrong with the first cross join operation but I can't figure out what exactly and how can I replace it with any other join.

Sooo...I've made some corrections:

```
select distinct RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(wte.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))) as orig_name, edited_name FROM wordsToEdit wte
       left join (select RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(STUFF(ISNULL(STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name),
                                    ''),RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                    PATINDEX('%'+a.name, ISNULL(STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name),
                                    ''),RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))))),len(a.name),
                                        ''), STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name)+1,
                                    '')))) as edited_name
        from (select name from abbEx union select full_name from abbEx) a
         cross join (select names FROM wordsToEdit) b) c on wte.names like '%'+edited_name+'%'
```

Now I'm getting this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|   orig_name                                                   |   edited_name                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   cut me edited one                                           |   edited one                      |
|   delete this this must not be deleted delete this            |   this must not be deleted        |
|   dt hello world                                              |   hello world                     |
|   save this words nn                                          |   save this words                 |
|   this one cm wasnt edited too                                |   <null>                          |
|   this one wasnt edited                                       |   <null>                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

But how do I put values from orig_name to edited_name where edited_name is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it

```
select distinct RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(wte.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))) as orig_name, ISNULL(edited_name, RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(wte.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))) as edited_name FROM wordsToEdit wte
       left join (select RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL(STUFF(ISNULL(STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name),
                                    ''),RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                    PATINDEX('%'+a.name, ISNULL(STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name),
                                    ''),RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))))),len(a.name),
                                        ''), STUFF(RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '))),
                            PATINDEX(a.name+'%', RTRIM(LTRIM(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(b.names), '-', ' '), '"', ''),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ')))),
                                len(a.name)+1,
                                    '')))) as edited_name
        from (select name from abbEx union select full_name from abbEx) a
         cross join (select names FROM wordsToEdit) b) c on wte.names like '%'+edited_name+'%'
```